# Host a site in local IIS with domain

Tags: iis-7.5

I want to host a site on local `IIS 7.5` for internal testing. But I want people can access over the internet.

For this on my `rackspace` server, I have created an `"A"` record with `subdomain.domainName.com` and pointed my `static IP address` to it.

In `IIS` I have created a `self-signed certificated` with `*.domainname.com` that it can be used to multiple sites.

Now, i have `published` a site to a `local directory` and in `IIS` I have created a site with `host name` the `same domain` for which I have created an `"A"` record.

I have added `http` and `https` `bindings` with `port 80 and 443` with the `same host name`.

But still my site is not working.

The error I am getting is `"This webpage is not available"`

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it my self.

I was missing `Port Forwarding` in my router software for `HTTPS`.

In my `web-application`, each `HTTP` request is automatically be converted to `HTTPS`. And I forgot to forward `Port 443's` request to the machine to which I have set the `static IP Address and DNS`.

After adding that port forwarding record to the router's software my application is working fine over internet.